# Store nth row elements in a list panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python.Could you help on follow
I have a dataframe as follows.
a,d,f & g are column names. dataframe can be named as `df1`

```
a   d   f   g
20  30  20  20
0   1   NaN NaN
```

I need to put second row of the df1 into a list without `NaN's`.
Ideally as follows.

x=[0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the second row using `df.iloc[1]` then using [`.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) remove the `nan` values, finally using [`.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method convert the series into python list.

Use:

```
x = df.iloc[1].dropna().astype(int).tolist()  
# x = [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html?highlight=itertuples)

So you would have something like taht:

```py
for row in df1.itertuples():
   row[0] #-> that's your index of row. You can do whatever you want with it, as well as with whole row which is a tuple now.
```

you can also use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.Series.dropna) like that:

```py
row_2 = df1.iloc[1].dropna().to_list()
```

Comment: `itertuples()` has worse performance than accessing and modifying an entire row or column at once

Comment: that's right. Thing is, that OP perhaps will generalize solution in the future. OP mentioned (s)he's a newbie. I don't ee any reason to not give more tips regarding crawling over dataframe.

Comment: nothing wrong with giving extra information; I just think it should be clarified that usually it's a good idea to avoid itertuples()